# shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier called before checking other method issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I'm trying to make a segue but I've a small issue which is that I'm clicking on a button and if the boolean is YES it will return YES in segue else return NO but everytime I have to click twice to check the textfield because it is passing first to `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` while it should check the IBAction first.

Please how I can I fix this issue?

```
- (IBAction)search:(id)sender{

if ([_txtfld.text isEqual:@"test"]) {

    push = YES; //Bolean
}

else {

    push = NO; //Bolean
  }
}

- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {

if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"SearchSegue"] && push==YES) {

    NSLog(@"Showed");
    return YES;
}
else{

    NSLog(@"Not showed");
    return NO;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to remove the segue from the action in your button, move it to the view controller and then invoke `performSegueWithIdentifier` in your `IBAction` method, or just have the logic in `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` and remove the `IBAction` method.

So, either -

```
- (IBAction)search:(id)sender{

    if ([self.txtfld.text isEqual:@"test"]) {

       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SearchSegue" sender:self];
    }

}
```

and get rid of `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` or get rid of the `IBAction` method and just have -

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {

   BOOL ret=YES;

   if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"SearchSegue"]) {
       if (![self.txtfld.text isEqual:@"test"]) {
          ret=NO;
       }
   }
   return ret;
}
```