# How to block storyboard segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue

I have my two ViewControllers: `FormViewController` segued to `CompleteRegisteringViewController`

My `FormViewController` contains textfields where user writes username, password, confirm password and so on... and a `ConfirmButton`
But it has conditions to complete registering, for example: if the password field text is different to the confirm password field text and so, if it is, the transition between `FormViewController` and `CompleteRegisteringViewController` is blocked and the user stay on the `FormViewController` to modify encountered errors.

I have already my idea to organize code, but the problem is how to "block" the segue ?

Comment: You may need to add more information on how the segues are being triggered, but I think you're just making an automatic segue when you push a button, and that's not really what you want.

Comment: Yes, excuse me, honestly I wrote that post quickly and I didn't pay attention to the quality... I have segued ConfirmButton to the CompleteRegisteringViewController, even I know that could not really work... Then, do you know another way with storyboard segues please ?

Comment: Yeah, remove the segue that goes from the button to the next view, and change it to be a segue from the view controller itself (so from the yellow circle at the top of the view controller) to the other view, and add a name to this segue

Answer (score 3):

You can use `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` method:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String!, sender: AnyObject!) -> Bool {
    if identifier == "YOUR SEGUE NAME" {
         // TODO: Do your validation here 
         // Return true if the validation pass, otherwise return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In objective-c You can actually do this by adding following method into your code

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender   {
    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"btnSegue"])
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }

}
```

Lets assume your segue is btnSegue.And if you need the segue to be performed based on some condition you can have following code

```
if(check)
{
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"btnSegue" sender:self]; 
}
```

Where check is `BOOL` which you can set true or false based on your condition.

Comment: You have the right idea about using `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` but your example implementation isn't correct. You should use the `if (check...` code in the shouldPerform to determine whether to return true/false, not whether to perform the segue - this is a valid approach but then you don't need shouldPerform... The two techniques are alternatives

Comment: You are getting it wrong if(check) is not inside shouldPerform it is on click of button where if the validations are upto expectations than it navigates to the defined segue. This is valid approach and we need both else you would not be able to navigate to other segue.

Comment: No, you either have an `IBAction` method that does the check, with the segue linked from the UIViewController, then you call `performSegueWithIdentifier` and no need for `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` because you have already performed the check in the `IBAction method` *OR* you have a segue triggered directly from the button (no `IBAction` method) and return YES/NO from `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` after performing the check - see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939361/shouldperformseguewithidentifier-called-before-checking-other-method-issue/27940074#27940074

Comment: Your scenario is different here the segue is directly linked from storyboard IBAction button so it will be performed no matter what, so to restrict that we need the `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier ` method. So in this case we require both of this mehtods

Comment: You are describing the second scenario of my answer - when the segue is linked directly from the button there is no need for `performSegueWithIdentifier` in code because the segue is linked directly.  If the button is linked to an `IBAction` (the first scenario) method then you simply don't call `performSegueWithIdentifier` if the condition isn't met - no need for `shouldPerformSegue` because the segue is never called when then condition isn't met.  In fact your implementation of `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` in this answer is flawed because it won't permit any other segues

Comment: It isn't what this question asked, but in my opinion a better approach is to disable the button until the conditions are met rather than having an enabled button that doesn't appear to work - or at least put some message on the screen as to why the button didn't work.

Comment: Paulw you are checking the condition for the validation in `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier ` while it can be performed on IBAction button and we can put this condition there. Both ways it can be performed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68836/discussion-between-paulw11-and-aadil-keshwani).